# Bitmap image appears dark

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-camerax

I'm using the CameraX Image Analyzer to scan the first image below. The camera manages to analyse it and I'm able to convert it into a bitmap, but when it converts, it appears dark (the second image). How do I get the bitmap to not appear dark?

[image: Image being scanned]

[image: Bitmap image]

The code below handles the image analysis and the conversion to a bitmap.

```
private class ImageAnalyzer(mContext: Context, mOnImageRequest: (File) -> Unit) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
val context = mContext
val onImageRequest = mOnImageRequest

@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError", "UnsafeOptInUsageError")
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
    val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
    if (mediaImage != null) {
        var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mediaImage.width, mediaImage.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        bitmap.setHasAlpha(true)
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, baos)
        val converter = YuvToRgbConverter(context)
        converter.yuvToRgb(mediaImage, bitmap)
    }
}}
```

---

```
class YuvToRgbConverter(context: Context) {
private val rs = RenderScript.create(context)
private val scriptYuvToRgb = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))

private var pixelCount: Int = -1
private lateinit var yuvBuffer: ByteArray
private lateinit var inputAllocation: Allocation
private lateinit var outputAllocation: Allocation

@Synchronized
fun yuvToRgb(image: Image, output: Bitmap) {
    if (!::yuvBuffer.isInitialized) {
        pixelCount = image.cropRect.width() * image.cropRect.height()
        val pixelSizeBits = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
        yuvBuffer = ByteArray(pixelCount * pixelSizeBits / 8)
    }
    imageToByteArray(image, yuvBuffer)

    if (!::inputAllocation.isInitialized) {
        val elemType = Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs)).setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.NV21).create()
        inputAllocation = Allocation.createSized(rs, elemType.element, yuvBuffer.size)
    }
    if (!::outputAllocation.isInitialized) {
        outputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output)
    }

    inputAllocation.copyFrom(yuvBuffer)
    scriptYuvToRgb.setInput(inputAllocation)
    scriptYuvToRgb.forEach(outputAllocation)
    outputAllocation.copyTo(output)
}

private fun imageToByteArray(image: Image, outputBuffer: ByteArray) {
    assert(image.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)

    val imageCrop = image.cropRect
    val imagePlanes = image.planes

    imagePlanes.forEachIndexed { planeIndex, plane ->
        val outputStride: Int
        var outputOffset: Int

        when (planeIndex) {
            0 -> {
                outputStride = 1
                outputOffset = 0
            }
            1 -> {
                outputStride = 2
                outputOffset = pixelCount + 1
            }
            2 -> {
                outputStride = 2
                outputOffset = pixelCount
            }
            else -> {
                return@forEachIndexed
            }
        }

        val planeBuffer = plane.buffer
        val rowStride = plane.rowStride
        val pixelStride = plane.pixelStride

        val planeCrop = if (planeIndex == 0) {
            imageCrop
        } else {
            Rect(
                imageCrop.left / 2,
                imageCrop.top / 2,
                imageCrop.right / 2,
                imageCrop.bottom / 2
            )
        }

        val planeWidth = planeCrop.width()
        val planeHeight = planeCrop.height()

        val rowBuffer = ByteArray(plane.rowStride)

        val rowLength = if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
            planeWidth
        } else {
            (planeWidth - 1) * pixelStride + 1
        }

        for (row in 0 until planeHeight) {
            planeBuffer.position(
                (row + planeCrop.top) * rowStride + planeCrop.left * pixelStride)

            if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
                planeBuffer.get(outputBuffer, outputOffset, rowLength)
                outputOffset += rowLength
            } else {
                planeBuffer.get(rowBuffer, 0, rowLength)
                for (col in 0 until planeWidth) {
                    outputBuffer[outputOffset] = rowBuffer[col * pixelStride]
                    outputOffset += outputStride
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```